# Is this normal bluebird/node.js/express error handling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, bluebird

So, I made this dumb typo and it took me quite some time to find it, because I always got an empty error from an executed mongoose query. I recreated the behavior to be a little more generic.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Promise = require('Bluebird');

router.patch('/test', function (req, res, next){
    var testPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { resolve(); })
    .then(function(result){

        if(thisIsAnExampleTypo){}

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'this will no be executed because of the typo',
            object: result
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        //console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            title: 'This will execute because of the typo in the then-function',
            error: {message: 'but it will also crash the node.js server if I log the error before this return statement'}
        });
    });
});
```

The code above will not crash the server but will execute the catch-function. If I uncomment the `console.log(err);` line it will crash the node server, which makes no sense to me. Also, it will only crash if I log the err, if I make it `console.log('test');` it will continue running.

I'm on Node.js v8.1.4, "express": "~4.14.0" and "bluebird": "^3.5.0".

Thanks in advance for any explanation/advice/help, it is not really a problem to me anymore, but this behavior really bugged me and I did not know where I should report this.

Comment: I can't reproduce the crash with that code.

Comment: I tried with the exact versions mentioned in the question.

Comment: the code looks good to me. Are you sure the server crashes and you arent just confused by the error msg the console.log produces?

Comment: btw you can do `Promise.resolve(data)` instead of `new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { resolve(data); })`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, maybe it's just a macOS (10.12.6) thing. Well, it says so in the node console that it crashed and nodemon is waiting for changes, which is not the case when the `console.log(err);` is not executed.